# stable/unstable equilibrium point in inverter with feedback circuit

Tags: oscillator, inverter, feedback, stability, oscillation

I am reading about ring oscillator [here](http://gram.eng.uci.edu/faculty/green/public/courses/270c/materials/lectures/Week6/Week6.pdf) (from page 4) and was stuck at the concept of stable/unstable equilibrium point.

How to know if an equilibrium point is stable or not? For example, the middle point in one inverter circuit is stable while it is unstable in two and three inverter circuits. 

 Can anyone explain why they are stable or unstable equilibrium point?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First circuit**: Stable equilibrium point because of negative feedback. An unwanted (random) small increase in V1 will reduce V2 (negative slope) while the feedback line works against it (positive slope) and does not allow such a change.

**Second circuit**: Unstable equilibrium point (in the middle) because of positive feedback (two inverter in series). An unwanted (random) small increase in V1 will increase V2 - and the feedback will support this change (also positive slope). The remaining points (latch) fulfill the stability properties (slopes of the curves) as mentioned above (case 1).

**Third circuit**: Stable equilibrium point (see case 1), however, the circuit will oscillate because we have positive feedback for a single frequency which fulfills Barkhausen´s oscillation condition: 180deg phase shift due to 3 inverters in series and another 180 deg due to propagation delays and capacitive phase shift.

(Comment: In contrast to the comment as given in the figure, I rather would say that the equilibrium point is a stable one (fixed and stable DC values); however, there is a signal swing around this stable point >>> Oscillation.

Another example: A BJT gain stage has a fixed quiescent (eqilibrium) point -  and the output signal swings around this point. Otherwise the term "equilibrium" would not make any sense.)